# Drupal Rooms - How to render the "Book This" form in a node reference full description?

Tags: 7, forms

I absolutely love this module, it works great and is exactly what I am looking for.

I am hoping to extend the functionality so I can render the "Book this" form on a referenced node rather than the bookable unit teaser. I want users to be able to book the room from the referenced node full description.

Here is what I have so far...

I have a content type called “Property display” which references a bookable unit type.
I have the “Rooms Availabity Reference” calendar rendering in the node full description.

What I need…

I would like the “Book This” button to be displayed on the full  node description underneath the rooms availability calendar. I understand that the form will need the correct dates added to it, but I am pretty good at Javascript, so I plan to validate whether the room is available by the user clicking on the availability calendar.

All I need is a little push in the right direction! I am happy to post my final code if anyone else is interested.

My best guess at the minute is to preprocess Product display node and call:

```
$booking_form = drupal_get_form('book_units_per_type_form', $units_per_type, $start_date, $end_date, $booking_parameters, $b_units, $type); 

print render($booking_form);
```

I can then use Javascript to create a custom date widget that sets the $start_date & $end_date of the form, and validates whether the room is available. I need to know how to how to load in the bookable unit parameters of the referenced bookable unit in my node preprocess function. Or if there is an easier way. –

Comment: Do you have any code so far? Also, this site is not a forum. So no "any help" or "thanks", please. Ask a *question*. In a way that will make it possible to post *answer*. Answer that will be either true and useful, or not. That's the way we work here. And for "thank you, it was all I needed", we have an accept mark. For general "thanks, useful", we have upvotes.

Comment: Just curious if you ever got this to work. If so can you post an update about it (eg in the format of "your own" answer. Also, I assume your question is about the https://www.drupal.org/project/rooms module (consider adding a link in your question details to the module).